# Is there a way to clear all cookies on a browser in one go?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

```
app.get("clear-cookies", (req, res) => {
    res.clearCookie(key)
    res.send("<h1>Cookies Cleared! </h1>");
});
```

The code above expects the key of the cookie to be cleared but what I want is to clear all the cookies stored on the web browser in one go. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in way to do this. Loop over all the cookies, clearing each of them.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that you're ONLY clearing cookies for the domain of this incoming request.  You can't affect other cookies in the browser at all.